# Laravel application getting 502 bad gateway error on EKS

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to run a legacy php larval app on my EKS cluster.

I have containerized the application via the docker file below

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y nginx

# PHP_CPPFLAGS are used by the docker-php-ext-* scripts
ENV PHP_CPPFLAGS="$PHP_CPPFLAGS -std=c++11"

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache \
    && apt-get install libicu-dev -y \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && apt-get remove libicu-dev icu-devtools -y
RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
        echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-opocache-cfg.ini

COPY nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY entrypoint.sh /etc/entrypoint.sh

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/mysite
RUN chmod +x /etc/entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /var/www/mysite

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/etc/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And the nginx-site.conf

```
server {
    root    /var/www/mysite/web;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    index app.php index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 30m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

The docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    expose:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - ./source:/source
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./source:/source
```

I have deployed nginx ingress controller provided by the official Kubernetes GitHub via helm and it looks something like this.

```yaml
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.35.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-ing
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.48.1"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: my-ing-ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-ing
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-ing
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: "k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.48.1@sha256:e9fb216ace49dfa4a5983b183067e97496e7a8b307d2093f4278cd550c303899"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle: 
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/my-ing-ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=external-nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/my-ing-ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
                drop:
                - ALL
                add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe: 
            failureThreshold: 5
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe: 
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 10254
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources: 
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      nodeSelector: 
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      affinity: 
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                operator: In
                values:
                - ingress-nginx
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      serviceAccountName: my-ing-ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: my-ing-ingress-nginx-admission
```

I have deployed my application via yaml like the one below.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: tardis
  labels:
    monitoring: prometheus
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: website
  namespace: tardis
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: website
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: website
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: website
          image: image directory on ecr
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: tardis
  name: website
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 9000
  selector:
    app: website

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: website
  namespace: tardis
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: external-nginx
  rules:
  - host: home.tardis.kr
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: website
            port:
              number: 9000
```

When I check the log of the pods, it seems to indicate that it is running fine.

```
[27-Apr-2022 23:33:23] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 25
[27-Apr-2022 23:33:23] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

However, when I try to access the address on mentioned in my ingress, it gives a "502 Bad Gateway Nginx" error.

I am really new to devops and even newer to php or larval.

If there is anything wrong with the way I containerized the application, or the way I deployed it, any sort of feedback would be much appreciated!!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: thank you for including so many of your details, however, you didn't include the curl you used to test, since Ingress (doubly so the way yours in written) are dispatched via the `host:` header, so if you just fired up your browser to `whatever-us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` or `111.2.33.444:30123` that'd be a fine reason it didn't work. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72036421/edit) and include how you tested and the outcome

Answer (score -1):

Think this was a problem had to do something with the dockerfile. I followed the [instruction](https://gbengaoni.com/blog/Deploy-a-Laravel-App-to-Amazon-EKS-in-5-minutes-a94a41436157) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).